# Is it possible to track meter readings in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash

I'd like to keep the record of, for example, water and electricity consummation. Is it possible to properly implement a pseudo-account in GnuCash to store the meters' readings? Even more, having the current electricity cost and the delta between readings, calculate the amount of money to pay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not native functionality, but you could probably do it.

You could create a fake security/currency for the meter type (kWh, whatever gas/water get measured in ).

Updating would be a pain, though. You'd have to go read it and enter the data manually -- unless it was a smart meter, and then you could probably build some sort of script for it.

In terms of figuring how much to pay -- maybe have an account in liabilities for stuff you haven't paid for yet, and another in assets for what you have paid for?

This seems like it could be a lot more complicated than it's worth.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to Money.StackExchange!  Take a look around the site and check out our [FAQ].

Comment: How can I create a fake currency in terms of consumer units? There's only fixed list of currencies available during the account creation.

Comment: When you're creating the account, use Account Type: Stock, and then you can create your own security. It's a hack, but might get you what you want.